# How do I shutdown Meteor Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, terminal, server, database

I kind of know how to shutdown Mongo, not sure if its right.

```
use admin

db.shutDownServer()
```

This had no effect with Meteor Mongo.
FYI started learning how to use a computer recently, pardon the lack of abilities.

Comment: have you tried typing control-c in the mongo terminal window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to shutdown mongo server run follow command in your system terminal:

```
mongod --shutdown
```

If you want to exit from mongo shell use `exit` command

If you really want to force shutdown your built-in meteor mongo (I don't khow why), you should go to meteor mongo shell using `meteor mongo` and run next:

```
use admin
db.adminCommand({shutdown : 1, force : true})
```